# Sending binary file via socket in C (from Windows to Linux)

Tags: c, file, sockets, transfer

I'm trying to send a file via socket using polar ssl.  The client (Windows) sends the file to the server (Linux) but when the file gets there, it's corrupted.

Does anybody how can I solve that?

To send:

```
fopen("file.zip","ab");//opening file
ssl_write()//sending file
```

To receive:

```
fopen("file.zip","wb");//opening file
ssl_read()//getting file
```

Comment: What exactly does "corrupt" mean? Have you compared octal dumps?

Comment: Doesn't "ab" mean append/binary?  Why wouldn't you do "rb"?

Comment: Can you show us the code reading the file and sending the data, and the code receiving/writing on the server?

Comment: problem with the ssl keys? have you checked the return values of the calls? :)

Comment: Have you tried doing an md5sum on both files?

Answer (score 0):

Could be something to do with [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?